# Check headers of a sent e-mail (by sendmail)

Tags: email, freebsd, sendmail, smtp-headers

When I send an e-mail in console, like:

```
echo "Body of the message" | mail -s "Some clever subject" my.address@myisp.com
```

I would like to check the headers of the e-mail once it is sent.

They do not show up in `/var/log/maillog` and when I check the mailbox (using `mail`), there's no "Sent" folder, I can only see received e-mails.

Is there any place where the *sent* e-mails are stored, that would allow to check their headers? (Or do I need to setup such a place? How?)

sendmail's configuration is quite the default one (only added an alias).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying messages to a `Sent` folder is normally done by the Mail User Agent.  I am not aware of a switch to `mail` that would do this.  However, you could add you userid to the list of addresses on the command line to get a copy of the message.  There should be a switch to deliver the copy as a blind carbon-copy.

The copy will contain a subset of the headers that exist on the message when it is finally delivered.  It will contain the key headers such as `To:`, `From:`, `Subject:`, `Message-id:` and `Date:`.  Other headers get added as the message is passed from server to server for delivery.

Comment: Well this is at least a workaround. The switch is `-b`, it can be used like this for instance to send a blind copy to root: `echo "Body of the message" | mail -s "Some clever subject" -b root my.address@myisp.com`